# xmlfile to php array

Tags: php, arrays, xml

i want to create an php array from an xml-file like this

test.xml

```
 object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (2) { ["uebertragung"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#5 (1) { ["@attributes"]=> array(9) 
{ ["art"]=> string(7) "OFFLINE" ["umfang"]=> string(4) "TEIL" 
["modus"]=> string(3) "NEW" ["version"]=> string(5) "1.2.7" ["sendersoftware"]=> string(7) "crm11" ["senderversion"]=> string(3) "1.1" 
["techn_email"]=> string(18) "support@mail.com" ["timestamp"]=> string(19)
 "2014-06-01T10:00:00" ["regi_id"]=> string(7) "ABCD143" } } 
["anbieter"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#4 (3) { ["anbieternr"]=> 
string(6) "144185" ["firma"]=> string(14) "redfirm" 
["immobilie"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#6 (7) { ["objektkategorie"]=> object(SimpleXMLElement)#7 ...
```

mycode:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("test.xml") or die("Error: Cannot read xml file");
var_dump($xml);
echo "show1: " .$xml->openimmo->uebertragung->{'art'} . "<br>";
echo "show2: " .$xml->openimmo->uebertragung['art'];
```

show 1+2 show nothing, can someone help me, i dont understand the array structure ?

Answer (score 0):

The art is an attribute, so you can get its value by

```
$xml->openimmo->uebertragung->attributes()->art
```

More here
http://php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.attributes.php

Comment: changing to this causes an error:

   echo "show1: " .$xml->openimmo->uebertragung->attributes()->art . "<br>";

Comment: PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function attributes() on null in /var/www/vhosts/intranet/httpdocs/immo_eintragen_db.php on line 21

Comment: Seeing the object it must be $xml->uebertragung->attributes()->art

Comment: You are welcome. If it works, please accept the answer.